# How will Lucy "make use" of a deep space atomic clock?

Tags: deep-space, time, atomic-clock, lucy-asteroid-mission

The entry for Lucy in Wikipedia's [Selection of Discovery Mission 13 and 14; Finalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_of_Discovery_Mission_13_and_14#Finalists) says:

> The mission will make use of the [Deep Space Atomic Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Atomic_Clock).<sup>81</sup>
>
> <sup>81</sup>https://www.universetoday.com/122822/surveying-the-fossils-of-planet-formation-the-lucy-mission/

The Universe Today article says only:

> NASA has also offered an additional \$5 to \$30 million in funding if mission planners choose to incorporate a laser communications system, a 3D woven heat shield, a Deep Space atomic clock, and/or ion engines.

and the linked [Deep Space Atomic Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Atomic_Clock) article does not mention Lucy, nor is the mission mentioned in any of the questions below nor their answer.

**Question:** So I'd like to ask: *How will Lucy "make use" of a deep space atomic clock?*

---

Deep Space Atomic Clock Q&A that don't currently mention Lucy:

- [Where would one deploy deep space atomic clocks?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36606/12102)
- [How does an onboard atomic clock help interplanetary navigation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36663/12102)
- [Help understanding exactly how an atomic clock facilitates “self-driving spacecraft” when paired with an onboard camera?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36692/12102)
- [Why does the Deep Space Atomic Clock have such a short mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45484/12102)
- [How high is the first Deep Space Atomic Clock orbiting? Does it receive radiation equivalent to that in deep space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38480/12102)
- [How far from earth have atomic clocks (or ultra-stable oscillators) been placed and monitored?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14682/12102)

Comment: More about Lucy: [Where can I read about Lucy's complete propulsion system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49947/12102)

Comment: I look forward to that answer! My guesses are the following: with a DSAC the frequency of the onboard telecommunication system will be drastically more precise. This can enable one-way ranging, better resolution for ranging data when tracking the spacecraft, and probably higher communication bandwidth (less error correction bits).

Comment: @ChrisR and by collecting "an additional \$5 to \$30 million in funding" :-)

Comment: Speculation: the extra funding might be to fly a technology demonstrator developed at NASA. It could bring an advanced prototype from TRL6 to TRL9 (the highest level).